# Issue when adding two JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to add two JPanels to a JFrame, one with a simple backround and another one with buttons etc. Either I get only buttons or only the background. I can't find a solution to my problem anywhere, so any help would be appreciated. I'm still new to Java, so please don't hate.

GuiMainMenu:

```
public class GuiMainMenu extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7936366600070922227L;

    Color blue = new Color(114, 137, 218);
    Color gray = new Color(44, 47, 51);
    Color white = new Color(255, 255, 255);

    ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("image.png").getImage());

    public static int width;
    public static int height;

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    JLabel l = new JLabel();
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel();
    JLabel l2 = new JLabel();
    JButton b = new JButton();
    JButton b1 = new JButton();
    JButton b2 = new JButton();
    String title = "-";

    
    public GuiMainMenu() {
        setSize(m.X, m.Y);
        setTitle(title);
        setResizable(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addKeyListener(this);

        p.setLayout(null);

        width = getWidth();
        height = getHeight();

        getRootPane().addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                width = getWidth();
                height = getHeight();

                addButtons();
                addLabels();
            }
        });

        addLabels();
        addButtons();
        
        add(p);
        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addLabels() {
        l.setSize(width, height);
        l.setLocation(5, -40);
        l.setText("x");
        l.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        l.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        l.setForeground(blue);
        l.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.PLAIN, 15));

        l1.setSize(width, height);
        l1.setLocation(-22, -40);
        l1.setText("y");
        l1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        l1.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        l1.setForeground(blue);
        l1.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.PLAIN, 15));

        l2.setText("test label");
        l2.setSize(width, height);
        l2.setLocation(0, -75);
        l2.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        l2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        l2.setForeground(blue);
        l2.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 26));

        p.add(l);
        p.add(l1);
        p.add(l2);
        validate();
    }

    public void addButtons() {
        b.setText("button0");
        b.setFocusable(false);
        b.setBorder(null);
        b.setLocation(width / 2 - 200, height / 2 - 35);
        b.setSize(400, 35);
        b.setForeground(white);
        b.setBackground(blue);
        b.addActionListener(this);

        b1.setText("button1");
        b1.setFocusable(false);
        b1.setBorder(null);
        b1.setLocation(width / 2 - 200, height / 2 + 10);
        b1.setSize(400, 35);
        b1.setForeground(white);
        b1.setBackground(blue);
        b1.addActionListener(this);

        p.add(b);
        p.add(b1);
        validate();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    }
}
```

ImagePanel Class:

```
class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7270956677693528549L;
    private Image img;

    public ImagePanel(String img) {
        this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
    }

    public ImagePanel(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, GuiMainMenu.width, GuiMainMenu.height, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have quite a few issues.  A JFrame has a default [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html).  You can add one JPanel to the CENTER and the other JPanel to the BEFORE_LINE_STARTS.  You should read your Image with the ImageIO class so you get an error message if there's a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p.setLayout(null);
```

Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

> Either I get only buttons or only the background

```
add(p);
add(panel);
```

The default layout manager for a JFrame is the BorderLayout. If you don't specify a constraint both components get added to the CENTER. However only the last one added will be displayed.

Try the following to see the difference:

```
add(p, BorderLayout.PAGE_STRT);
add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

> one with a simple backround and another one with buttons etc.

However above is not what you want. Swing components have a parent/child relationship. So what you really need is:

```
backgroundPanel.add(buttonPanel);
add(backgroundPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Note I used more meaningful names because "p" and "panel" and not descriptive. Use descriptive names for variable so people can understand what they mean.

Comment: Alright, I get the relationship thing. Now everything is (kinda) displayed correctly. However, I don't understand how to change the locations of buttons, labels etc. without setLayout(null). Is there any documentation or similar that could explain this further to me?

Comment: *I don't understand how to change the locations of buttons, labels etc. without setLayout(null).* - I gave you documentation.  What part about the working examples found in the tutorial on `Layout Managers` do you not understand? I can't guess what you find confusing. Ask a specific question (in another posting since your original question has been answered), if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to display a JFrame with a background image and various components. I think after reviewing your code that there is some misunderstanding on your part causing the problem.

I've created a short snippet of code that does the basics and maybe helps you to solve your problem. (Not tested!)

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GuiMainMenu extends JFrame{

    private BufferedImage imageBackground;  // TODO: load your background image

    public GuiMainMenu(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        // TODO: setLayout if needed
        JPanel panel = (JPanel)add(new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(imageBackground, 0, 0, this);
            }
        });
        addOtherComponents(panel);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Your Title her");
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addOtherComponents(JPanel panel){
        //TODO: add the needed Stuff
        //panel.add ...
    }
}
```

Comment: At that point in the code, `this` refers to the `JPanel`, but it *also* implements `ImageObserver`.